# How to retrieve all the classes for certain object

Tags: php, class, oop, object

I am trying to check one object using `var_dump`

```
$this->RTEObj = t3lib_div::makeInstance('tx_tinymce_rte_pi1');
var_dump($this->RTEObj);
```

It shows:

```
object(tx_tinymce_rte_pi1)#60 (3) { ["forceUTF8"]=> bool(true) ["errorLog"]=> array(0) { } ["ID"]=> string(0) "" }
```

so I checked file:class.tx_tinymce_rte_pi1.php, it shows:

```
class tx_tinymce_rte_pi1 extends tx_tinymce_rte_base {
...
}
```

`tx_tinymce_rte_base` may aslo extend the other class. so my question is:

Is there a way that I can output all the classes that object(`$this->RTEObj`)derived? something like  `tx_tinymce_rte_pi1`<- `tx_tinymce_rte_base`<-`...`?

Comment: Read [this page](http://php.net/get_parent_class) (also look at the comments).

Comment: I am sure we can also use Reflection

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course you can do that, try following function:

```
function getAllClasses($class) {
    $instance = new $class;
    echo get_class($instance) . " <- ";

    while($string = get_parent_class($instance)) {
        echo $string . " <- ";

        $instance = new $string();
    }
}
```

And then, you use 
       getAllClasses(new tx_tinymce_rte_pi1());
and it prints you what you want :)